# Easter calculation in bash yields constant result

Tags: linux, bash

So basically i have this issue with my Easter calculator, its a bash script that i have checked on shellcheck but with little to no luck, this is the code :

```
#!/shell/bash

read -r -p year
Am19=$((year% 19))
m19=$((19*(Am19)))
Am4=$((year%7))
m4=$((19*(Am4)))
Am2=$((year%4))
m2=$((2*(Am2)))
Av2=$((16+(m19)))
v2=$((Av2%30))
Av1=$((6*(v2)+m4+m2))
v1=$((Av1%7))
p=$((v1+v2))
echo "$p"
```

Everything appears fine but every time i input a number it always comes out with the result 21
I cant spot any issue, any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very interesting issue, especially since [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) didn't point out the problem. The problem is in the first line

```
 read -r -p year
```

Here `year` is not a variable name but a prompt (a literal string to be printed) given to `-p`. From `help read` (shortened version):

> `read [-r] [-p prompt] [name ...]`
>   If no NAMEs are supplied, the line read is stored in the `REPLY` variable.

The string entered by the user is stored in the variable `REPLY` and not in `year`. The variable `year` remains unset and will expand to `0` in an arithmetic context like `((…))`.

Use `read -r -p year year` to fix the problem, or even better

```
read -r -p 'enter a year: ' year
```

#### Further improvements

- Is `#! /shell/bash` really correct? I never heard of a system using such a path. I would expect `/bin/bash`.
- You can do assignments inside `((…))`, there is no need for a subshell. Write `((a=b+c))` instead of `a=$((b+c))`.